# A weird problem with variable in JavaScript regexp pattern

Tags: javascript

I want input a number to find, so the regexp pattern must be dynamic, but I have encountered some strange problems.

Here is the example code:

```
let list = `
[170] (50-20-3) Fant
[173] (50-20-3) Chi
[174] (50-20-3) Trib
[176] (50-20-3) Fant
[177] (50-20-3) Emo
[178] (50-20-3) Fa
`;

// In fact, this 'find' variable is origin by user input.
let find = 170;
let re = new RegExp("[" + find + "](.+)");
let found = list.match(re)[1];

document.write(found);
```

According to the example, what I expected is:

```
 (50-20-3) Fant
```

However, I actually got this:

```
70] (50-20-3) Fant
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to quote the brackets with a quote for the quote, because the string is not a regular expression and by converting it to a regular expression, the first quoted qoute is converted to a quote and this quotes the bracket.

> ```
> value    type
> -----    ------------------
> '\\['    string
> /\[/     regular expression
> ```

A bracket in a regular expression denotes a character class.

```js
let list = `
[170] (50-20-3) Fant
[173] (50-20-3) Chi
[174] (50-20-3) Trib
[176] (50-20-3) Fant
[177] (50-20-3) Emo
[178] (50-20-3) Fa
`;


let find = 170;
let re = new RegExp("\\[" + find + "\\](.+)");
let found = list.match(re)[1];

console.log(found);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, you saved my afternoon. Then, why use two escape characters?

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation, I understand. :)

Comment: Note that the actual user input should also be escaped unless you want the user to be able to enter a regular expression.